# Hardware requirements for a Unity game

Tags: unity, steam, hardware, unity-urp, requirements

I am listing a game on Steam and need to set system requirements.

The game is a online 3D game using Universal Render Pipeline with low poly assets.

My idea was to copy the requirements for a similar game made with Unity URP.

Do you have some suggestions for games or a better solution?

*Please dont mark this as a duplicate of a 12 year old question, this is specific to Unity URP.*

Comment: Sorry, but there is nothing specific about Unity URP that is not already answered in the linked question. The process to figure out the minimum requirements of a game did not change in the past 10 years.

Comment: @Philipp Im not going to run around town asking people if I can try running my game on their computer

Comment: Well, if it is an online game, then you are going to need a whole lot of playtesters during development anyway. While you are collecting feedback regarding the balance of your game mechanics, you can also collect feedback regarding the performance.